# ConfigParser: Check If variable in Config File exists

Tags: python, variables, configuration-files, configparser

I am currently trying to check if my config file has a variable in it.
In the documentation I only saw a check for the sections but not a variable inside the section.

Current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from configparser import ConfigParser

def ImportConfig(arg):
    config_file = ConfigParser()
    config_file.read("configFile")
    config = config_file[""+arg+""]
    
    If config['variable'] exists:
        do something...
```

arg is the section name that I give my script as a parameter.

Comment: In practice, it's often easier to fallback to a default, if the variable doesn't exist e.g. `tcp_port = config.getint('control', 'TCP_PORT', fallback=5005)` - where if the variable TCP_PORT does not exist in section 'control' the value 5005 is returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import configparser

spam = 'some_section'
eggs = 'some_key'
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.cfg')
if config.has_option(spam, eggs):
    # do something

# alternative

if config.get(spam, eggs, fallback=None):
   # do something
```

you can use [has_option()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.has_option) or [get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.get)